# How do I update this input value thats already preset using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this array of objects that I set as values in input fields. However, I want to be able to change those inputs too. Currently im unable to change the inputs when I type, its stuck on the value I set.

I want to keep those values but also type in another value.
Note: I dont want it as a placeholder

```js
  [
{nutrient: "Energy", per100: "449kcal", per35: "157kcal", id: 6}
 {nutrient: "Fat", per100: "24.4g", per35: "8.6g", id: 1}
 {nutrient: "Saturated fat", per100: "4.5g", per35: "1.6g", id: 2}
 {nutrient: "Monounsaturated fat", per100: "13.6g", per35: "4.8g", id: 3}
]
```

```js
<div>
      <div>
        { Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <input type="text"   value={key} id="name" name="productName"  />
        ))}
      </div>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <input type="text"  value={val} id="name" name="productName" />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a read of the React documentation about controlled components. You are telling the text inputs to always have that value, and are not updating the state that is driving the value of those inputs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

In general, if that data is passed in as a prop to this component, you should save that passed-in prop data in state. Your component can then update the state when the user is typing in the form, but your props always retain their values. That will achieve your goal of having that original data still available to you.

Comment: the thing is, the mapped value is being passed in as value, so its not passed in via state